# How to make a string in java understand current local time

Tags: java, string, datetime, time, duration

Here's my code, I'm trying to my 'calculateButton' variable to understand the current local time so that it can use it in the math equation. Thanks for taking a look. By the current time, I mean the time currently being shown on my computer or the time zone I'm in.

```
     private void bednowButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   //variable declaration
   String calculateButton, outputTime;
   double outputtimeConstant;
   calculateButton= "";

   //math
   outputtimeConstant = +104;
   outputTime = calculateButton + outputtimeConstant;

   //output
   bednowOutput.setText(outputTime) ;
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean by "current local time", and how you intend to use it in a "math equation".

Comment: LocalDateTime.now() perhaps?

Comment: @Stephen C By math equation I mean outputTime = (whatever the time is) + outputtimeconstant. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @KevinO Yea maybe! How would I implement that in this situation? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: What are the units for "time"?

Comment: Please give a precise example of a current time of day and the result you want. I believe this would greatly help understanding. For example, if the current time is 08:05 and the constant to add is 104, should the result be 09:09 (1 hour 4 minutes later) or 09:49 (104 minutes later) or something else?

Comment: Java is a typed language. A `String` is just a string, it does not "understand" time. You need to use one of the date/time related classes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date and time just use static method now() of LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime classes (you mentioned time zone here, so I'm specifying this implementation as well). For some math with these objects afterwards just use their instance methods, like plusDays, plusHours... and so on. I'd recommend reading documentation of these classes, they are quite useful.

If you want to have a String representation simply call toString() method.